# PHP parsing html post array problems

Tags: php, arrays, json, post

I have problem with parsing post array from html. It's work on one server, but not work on another (public server).
I user data from one array (make in javascript) to use other posts and populate database. Code made from frontend with var data[]; JSON.stringify(data);

```
        $predmeti = json_decode($_POST['predmeti']);
        foreach($predmeti as $predmet)
        {
            $podaci = array(
                'id_pohadja' => $_POST['pohadja'],
                'id_predmet' => $predmet,
                'prvo_polugodiste' => $_POST[$predmet . '-prvo_polugodiste'],
                'prvo_zakljucna' => $_POST[$predmet . '-prvo_zakljucna'],
                'drugo_polugodiste' => $_POST[$predmet . '-drugo_polugodiste'],
                'drugo_zakljucna' => $_POST[$predmet . '-drugo_zakljucna']
            );

            try {
                $database->snimiOcene($podaci);
            } catch(Exception $ex) {
                die($ex->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Recived error:

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

HTML:

```
                        <input type="hidden" name="predmeti" id="frmOcenePredmeti" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var predmeti = [];
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("<tr>");
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("<td>" + key + "</td>");
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("<td>" +
                            "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
                            "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-prvo_polugodiste" + "\"" +
                            "   value=\"" + value["prvo_polugodiste"] + "\"" +
                            "   />" +
                        "</td>");
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("<td>" +
                            "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
                            "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-prvo_zakljucna" + "\"" +
                            "   value=\"" + value["prvo_zakljucna"] + "\"" +
                            "   size=\"2\" />" +
                        "</td>");
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("<td>" +
                            "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
                            "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-drugo_polugodiste" + "\"" +
                            "   value=\"" + value["drugo_polugodiste"] + "\"" +
                            "   />" +
                        "</td>");
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("<td>" +
                            "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
                            "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-drugo_zakljucna" + "\"" +
                            "   value=\"" + value["drugo_zakljucna"] + "\"" +
                            "   size=\"2\" />" +
                        "</td>");
                        $("#tblOcene tbody").append("</tr>");
                        predmeti.push(value['id_predmet']);
                    });
                    $("#frmOcenePredmeti").val(JSON.stringify(predmeti));
```

Working server print_r($predmeti):

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 7 [5] => 11 [6] => 19 [7] => 20 [8] => 21 [9] => 22 [10] => 23 [11] => 13 )
```

Not working server print_r($predmeti): Print nothing

Comment: Post the content of `var_dump($predmeti)`

Comment: When I recive $_POST['predmeti']  on one server get [1,2,3] and another [\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]. Maybe is problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript:**

```
var predmeti = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var row = "";
    row += "<tr>";
    row += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
        "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-prvo_polugodiste" + "\"" +
        "   value=\"" + value["prvo_polugodiste"] + "\"" +
        "   />" + "</td>";

    row += "<td>" + "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
        "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-prvo_zakljucna" + "\"" +
        "   value=\"" + value["prvo_zakljucna"] + "\"" +
        "   size=\"2\" />" + "</td>";

    row += "<td>" + "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
        "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-drugo_polugodiste" + "\"" +
        "   value=\"" + value["drugo_polugodiste"] + "\"" +
        "   />" + "</td>";

    row += "<td>" + "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"" +
        "   name=\"" + value["id_predmet"] + "-drugo_zakljucna" + "\"" +
        "   value=\"" + value["drugo_zakljucna"] + "\"" +
        "   size=\"2\" />" + "</td>";

    row += "</tr>";

    $("#tblOcene tbody").append(row);
    predmeti.push(value['id_predmet']);
});
$("#frmOcenePredmeti").val(JSON.stringify(predmeti));
```

**Try this server side code:**

```
$predmeti = json_decode($_POST['predmeti'], true);
if(is_array($predmeti)) {
    foreach($predmeti as $predmet)
    {
        $podaci = array(
            'id_pohadja' => $_POST['pohadja'],
            'id_predmet' => $predmet,
            'prvo_polugodiste' => $_POST[$predmet . '-prvo_polugodiste'],
            'prvo_zakljucna' => $_POST[$predmet . '-prvo_zakljucna'],
            'drugo_polugodiste' => $_POST[$predmet . '-drugo_polugodiste'],
            'drugo_zakljucna' => $_POST[$predmet . '-drugo_zakljucna']
        );

        try {
            $database->snimiOcene($podaci);
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try, not help.

Answer (score 0):

I trim recived string from post [\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"] and remove all \ and ". Then decode JSON and use it like array.